# How to extract single Header value from multiple values extracted using regular expression extractor in JMeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter

**I need to extract this highlighted value as authorization token:**

```
Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1 
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization
Authorization: **eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2IiwiY3R5IjoiSldUIn0..ghNqO8N_J_y6FrxTPf03Aw.UwbOxNenbLL8qxoD89AY0Z89190AbiJh6xVlF20RLA3XN5orf3qX9AXoNNSf_qzj3dcu2G5RVdW9DZ2ERez0HEvMkYj871nvDoca4-V1WaeAOkSI3b72UbMoWA4RLnIfAHY64ELJJowXNAS5m0K8MePzHXtAbsQYR0F_jPlPwKIUozOhA4idbMy_YjmmYq6s4PEzM-FURJJVmvO9H7OneXwR01e2S5TVb8AUOVkEk_BeRz5oUsQEl3orb-5it-lmd6upDR_DZqsVJxdlrtH57QexhNZPhLuISCk3YeN_pfXqE7RCv6UrUibSYLSAzVkg3A5TLcRoLtf3Es5e4ubh0RVoCElU1gLBVRQCc2INAdFLBDpqchZgavm2RllsDp9c1AQTv8pOWrNqMX2qQUO_uXF9JZpeJP8YnAC7e1XXtF3DWX-9waXg_g2JrbKxGLu3xTGau5g0IvL5DCTNR4uCIfVgTsS8tBbQKSBgN07qJOgB8prM_a5dAE5Y6F3Rd12-YXC37zwIngYWQ7ka_pOKdB98g6xXOKLWeltuZRvpqyQ32CYMKQXJpwubUh0xWAdND0kOQHj56Kyv2zGy2eOazS5v_68PrY4OYTqKBUEeh_AhO1TUYWj3X9vkDtcKye03d_nArxMstoHkaRE-3dwB3DmbYOKtGmfivQ1dwdW7dAEpj4zsuK49wKtu-ooH6rLxd8N2Z8owUQ6wPeOtfPgRb8VKl1tkgFIiE5hupHn-sXuC9ies_QaONKgOoaLt7uXOiIAx5ULw8jtv0iRL9wlkAQzcIv2U2cAy-QSlfzpczM8yUbBhtQOBs0DaF1iLBzztodvZvkvcG4CJXwCjnFaYwbDkI6yPipus8_0kilbJUzyBtG8NKhTseGgYqbdcA4T9t5WoIb2rKjiK1EdQuGysMjHy_H1hy8C7BK1Id5jlSOPTiZS6z4rWnzEjYupiHiAp8LR5_MWIjjaW9IjSanvZdS_zBUvrCiGDb549ep3PVLcD_tzyH49LDnwbW-NArsNwByiXRNFKD72RN_I8F0GSB-poi0fE4_EAg254xkGUvdVTEJSVC1Kcwe8bUetC9Bhn_27bxPf5EadTJK6lfA5uwDoZqfhB1bI5CIxEw1ylLSX1e4w-babjmAbRoBIos2dPms2PJqKQ9I0XTXOgEmN0JRg16UWQ9jSyZaF5zBG9PP_PLCbOJ20RnLXdxV76ohLuIE7TGI9JfJr5aC3y3cdxj8TqXZVnwArXwKSfKz_VeAKjwt1Aw7f0X98N17L872Tb9U7u_MVB89FqHkxD98pUvMUnW7-9pJQkhD8I-fWcP-bWf6KmfWnFywHrrpAnmPGu9pNFkzEHRLbT_bmj3JQxOQkrba7o9Eu1WHNw8tfHS1NOiP5evey5gZB7Ur8Ski83W3GCfmwxnuuj6aB58tsHJXaFbmwo-T1ILm_Dsdw6CRZyu68F4FPAvu60yrX2YLHS-N1xqsXV-emHp0wbAA5P_Hk_D0BHTYCntAMGyTE-gMoNXRLS_XfcztEkhjGam5TP07n8XBMo11tvX7xmCHievH0riF7L1zEf7AoUbBrA5MsBqeD9BjD8WVUF1IlQ_lBEZpPRxSTmoRkZFuWokmos-TiufquqlQlgs-4YfwYfCgCC2TOM7cWAYw4UV0mequ0nv2fFA972uaIuqOa2W0dkfxX434DTmb4_RupNevyi3JgQxWY9uuuC9enOGf5VpCDhz7sFsbrmSA55rH-EKdizNa7nvlCXC2HAY-u_8M6wxDCeQhC84QAlFfjWp3YaewPdvN3lXDLfN9iaW_voSFX_vv7OYDdU24l8ZaPn6fAJ5WcjlGtCFUPLIPHXGiBZI2EO-n4MZ9ftFJAWYk3VCiXjnRvP1Cqd2m_SuPP-GCUzEF2p1NnqsXZ4Q57YeUBCIydSNa02a4Ss1Ab4t2sg_hLqj0SRUith6oho-HB5w65-5BlepuymJPgq0b1YqpSVnuyAgyiyYQNE9LctNgms2AQeSw4QVMdyTFajf2-fry0CL8WqOad1bfo64TCrpVE28CwVroJ-t_YKI_w1NROzy_TRiRmmmtICvVurfmwtQB4oPgc7wlS2UDrppEvnQ_GeBeMEXFqO_EH-GHrugGmi33iz3ZrILdHJJH_O1eKa6EOREZ9mvJ3aiR23zagp07qZ7lOSCz_GIFY8S3hBQNgfYuZCYhWiaJGDkMwRsqG8_6o08P4sHJMLP2UTy6B_JNVvzDFlWo3FFXxESKdA2hyRe2Z6Y8C9aNgfpP7YrpM8rDk_UehyUwGBuYMgxCd3R9AeK7hkX7MNYB2rPl3dUQnVZiAaXkgE-YLtjN_e9QUy6TlebrF2-FEpN9OhTYi-WbEpSsagVm717IB3xBo7f1RFt5i_lxf2fuqAa_I5Lo8qU_bD8M_kZCL4Sh2bE2i8wkbTbuHnF1Gtaj6i5iuLSx_6q4anSbaxqSTWhaym5VDWTksV1cr7PJsga_3MPic26EZc1tlTbmVjeDmoHdSv99f1GDBK2hogqSrud-7gbMMQppofC8-7pjlEL_z-9_0oKlHhHVXCYg0yiQqk_w07-CfJ4cehU1LeC6nu-6NyU1iGVmJumxIkHT1FCa6ZPYRBcWGSw-MjBNp0l3l3jIOfsSWfoLOQVmbKze1Br4rHuB922J0Dwh8.0YAiHJMnOfXFeATSs_vKJg**
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 13 Sep 2018 10:28:51 GMT
Content-Length
```

My regular expression is : [regular expression extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avGGt.png)
but i am getting multiple values using this expression . How to get only one value of Authorization Token ? 
Please let me know .

Comment: What is **this highlighted value**? Please post some examples (before and after) and avoid using pictures, or at least add them as content and not as links.

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see using "RegExp Tester" mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener there is only one match for your headers:

[image: JMeter RegExp Tester View Results Tree]

Make sure to place the Regular Expression Extractor **as a child** of the HTTP Request sampler which header value you want to extract as the Regular Expression Extractor is sensitive to the [Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) therefore if it is located at the same level as HTTP Request samplers - it will extract the headers from all of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , i was unknown about the Scoping Rules you mentioned . Thanks alot ! it worked .

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can occur due to white space(s), change your Regular expression:

```
Authorization:(\s+)(.*)
```

And then use Template `$2$`, this will ignore any white spaces before the values

Comment: There was no white space . Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Authorization: "(.*?)"

And then use the Template $1$

Comment: that quotation mark is not mentioned in the text it didnt work .